# How are ultrasonic bursts generated electronically?

Tags: ultrasound

I'm curious how the ultrasonic sensors generate bursts from pulse trains electronically. Here is a plot about how a burst look like?

[image]

I couldn't find any illustrative explanation about it.

Comment: It's not clear what you want explained. Ultrasonic transmitters act like loudspeakers. Ultrasonic receivers act like microphones.

Comment: Is your plot the burst or the echo. To me it look like the response. Can you add some description on how you are generating the signal

Comment: JIm Dearden understood what I was asking about..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The ultrasonic transducer can be **modelled** in terms of resistances, capacitances and inductance (RCL).

Whenever you get RCL circuits you get **resonance effects** (the frequency it want to vibrate at) due to the LC part of the circuit.

A pulse input momentarily moves the circuit away from its equilibrium position and the system will start to vibrate at its resonant frequency. Through each cycle some of the energy is lost and so the amplitude of vibration decreases with time. This is called damping.

For comparison I've shown a simple mechanical system which exhibits the same properties.

Typically these systems exhibit the same shape of output graph with the sinusoidal resonant frequency output rising to a maximum and then decaying more slowly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just one more thing, I always wondered why the reflected wave and transmitted waves do not corrupt each other in ultrasonic proximity sensors. Do you also have an opinion about it? And in my sensor the transducer freq. is given around 400kHz. Does that correspond to the interval between each bursts sent? And I would be very glad if you can link me the source of excitation pulse and damped response illustration.

Comment: Me thinks this question was closed prematurely

Comment: @user16307 No. This (400kHz) is the resonant frequency. (period about 2.5 microseconds). The excitation pulses are usually spaced at much large intervals to allow for time of travel and processing of signal. Waves pass through each other all the time. The only time they interact is when they meet at a point and time in space. You can try this out in a bath of water. Send a wave down to one end and let it reflect before sending another wave. As they pass (in opposite directions) they join, the amplitude gets larger and then they resolve back into two separate waves thus saving the Universe.